How to cancel a Jetton(TON) token transfer transaction
I have a problem with transaction rollback when transferring Jetton tokens: for example one user wants to transfer Jetton tokens to another user whose owner is another smart contract. The transfer is done in three transactions:

The first transaction is a tokenTransfer message that is sent to the sender's wallet, where he sends the necessary data such as the recipient's address, the number of tokens to be transferred, etc.
The second transaction is sending a transferInternal message to the recipient's wallet.
The third transaction is sending a tokenNotification message to the address of the owner of this wallet (the recipient's address).

Actually the problem may be the following: when the contract receives a tokenNotification message from the wallet contract and for some reason wants to roll back this transaction (for example, in the code that is responsible for processing the tokenNotification message, there are some checks that have not been passed), then he will be able to cancel only the transaction with the tokenNotification message (that is the third transaction), but the token transfer itself was in the second.
One of the proposed options was to send tokens back to the user, but the problem here is that transferring tokens back is another transaction that is initiated by my contract, which means my contract must pay a commission for the transfer. That is, the user can thus attack my contract, so that he will send many transactions that my contract will consider invalid and will try to send tokens back, spending his TON on the commission.
Here is code of my Jetton contract
@interface("org.ton.jetton.wallet")
contract JettonDefaultWallet {
    const minTonsForStorage: Int = ton("0.019");
    const gasConsumption: Int = ton("0.013");
    balance: Int as coins = 0;
    owner: Address;
    master: Address;

    init(owner: Address, master: Address){
        self.balance = 0;
        self.owner = owner;
        self.master = master;
    }

    receive(msg: TokenTransfer){
        // 0xf8a7ea5
        let ctx: Context = context(); // Check sender
        require(ctx.sender == self.owner, "Invalid sender");
        let final: Int =
            (((ctx.readForwardFee() * 2 + 2 * self.gasConsumption) + self.minTonsForStorage) + msg.forward_ton_amount); // Gas checks, forward_ton = 0.152
        require(ctx.value > final, "Invalid value");
        // Update balance
        self.balance = (self.balance - msg.amount);
        require(self.balance >= 0, "Invalid balance");
        let init: StateInit = initOf JettonDefaultWallet(msg.sender, self.master);
        let wallet_address: Address = contractAddress(init);
        send(SendParameters{
                to: wallet_address,
                value: 0,
                mode: SendRemainingValue,
                bounce: true,
                body: TokenTransferInternal{ // 0x178d4519
                    query_id: msg.query_id,
                    amount: msg.amount,
                    from: self.owner,
                    response_destination: msg.response_destination,
                    forward_ton_amount: msg.forward_ton_amount,
                    forward_payload: msg.forward_payload
                }.toCell(),
                code: init.code,
                data: init.data
            }
        );
    }

    receive(msg: TokenTransferInternal){

        // 0x178d4519
        let ctx: Context = context();                
        if (ctx.sender != self.master) {
            let sinit: StateInit = initOf JettonDefaultWallet(msg.from, self.master);
            require(contractAddress(sinit) == ctx.sender, "Invalid sender!");
        }
        // Update balance
        self.balance = (self.balance + msg.amount);
        require(self.balance >= 0, "Invalid balance");
        // Get value for gas
        let msg_value: Int = self.msg_value(ctx.value);
        let fwd_fee: Int = ctx.readForwardFee();
        if (msg.forward_ton_amount > 0) {
            msg_value = ((msg_value - msg.forward_ton_amount) - fwd_fee);
            send(SendParameters{
                    to: self.owner,
                    value: msg.forward_ton_amount,
                    mode: SendPayGasSeparately,
                    bounce: false,
                    body: TokenNotification{ // 0x7362d09c -- Remind the new Owner
                        query_id: msg.query_id,
                        amount: msg.amount,
                        from: msg.from,
                        forward_payload: msg.forward_payload
                    }.toCell()
                }
            );
        }
        // 0xd53276db -- Cashback to the original Sender
        if (msg.response_destination != null && msg_value > 0) {
            send(SendParameters{
                    to: msg.response_destination!!,
                    value: msg_value,
                    bounce: false,
                    body: TokenExcesses{query_id: msg.query_id}.toCell(),
                    mode: SendPayGasSeparately
                }
            );
        }
    }

    receive(msg: TokenBurn){
        let ctx: Context = context();
        require(ctx.sender == self.owner, "Invalid sender"); // Check sender

        self.balance = (self.balance - msg.amount); // Update balance
        require(self.balance >= 0, "Invalid balance");
        let fwd_fee: Int = ctx.readForwardFee(); // Gas checks
        require(ctx.value > ((fwd_fee + 2 * self.gasConsumption) + self.minTonsForStorage), "Invalid value - Burn");
        // Burn tokens
        send(SendParameters{
                to: self.master,
                value: 0,
                mode: SendRemainingValue,
                bounce: true,
                body: TokenBurnNotification{
                    query_id: msg.query_id,
                    amount: msg.amount,
                    sender: self.owner,
                    response_destination: msg.response_destination
                }.toCell()
            }
        );
    }

    fun msg_value(value: Int): Int {
        let msg_value1: Int = value;
        let ton_balance_before_msg: Int = (myBalance() - msg_value1);
        let storage_fee: Int = (self.minTonsForStorage - min(ton_balance_before_msg, self.minTonsForStorage));
        msg_value1 = (msg_value1 - (storage_fee + self.gasConsumption));
        return msg_value1;
    }

    bounced(msg: bounced<TokenTransferInternal>){
        self.balance = (self.balance + msg.amount);
    }

    bounced(msg: bounced<TokenBurnNotification>){
        self.balance = (self.balance + msg.amount);
    }

    get fun get_wallet_data(): JettonWalletData {
        return
            JettonWalletData{
                balance: self.balance,
                owner: self.owner,
                master: self.master,
                code: initOf JettonDefaultWallet(self.owner, self.master).code
            };
    }
}


There are some misconceptions in what you have described:

when the contract [let's call it R] receives a tokenNotification message from the wallet contract and for some reason wants to roll back this transaction (for example, in the code that is responsible for processing the tokenNotification message, there are some checks that have not been passed), then he will be able to cancel only the transaction with the tokenNotification message (that is the third transaction), but the token transfer itself was in the second.

in your terms R won't be able to roll back even the third transaction. Let's make a diagram:
S -[tokenTransfer]-> SW -[transferInternal]-> RW -[tokenNotification]-> R

each message is denoted here with -[op_name]->, contracts are in between. Transactions are done on each contract, i.e. a tx consists of:

receiving a message
calculating results
action (i.e. sending a message).

Once a message is sent, the tx is complete, and you can't roll it back. If R has received the tokenNotification from RW, than the tx on RW is complete.
What you can do is to

bounce a message (like, R can bounce tokenNotification), and it depends on RW implementation what RW will do with the bounced message. If it supports rolling back the whole saga, it will revert some changes and send another bounce message to SW etc, but most likely RW will just ignore it (well, I'm almost sure that that's the case for Jettons as I've read some of their code);
send Jettons back.

Note that even bouncing will require some commision (sending message requires gas), so any approach to reverting this chain requires some amount of TON. The only way to automate such reverting is to

implement Jettons that support such saga reverting and
send enough TON with the tokenTransfer message to allow the reverting process (ideally, in the case when reverting is not done, you have to also implement sending extra TON [not used for reverting] back from R to S).


You are right that if R message is received, then RW is already completed. This is actually the problem: tokens are transferred in transactions 1 and 2 (or SW and RW). In SW tokens are debited from the sender's wallet, in RW they are credited to the recipient's wallet. And in R some conditions are checked. If these conditions are not correct, we need to return tokens back. But we can't return them, because SW and RW transactions are already completed, we can only roll back the transaction R(tokenNotification), but it will not give anything.

The proposal to modify the Jetton contract is not suitable, because I want to work with many tokens of the Jetton standard. And if I add the necessary code to return tokens back or handle bounce messages, it doesn't mean that some other token can have the same mechanisms implemented.

The proposal to send enough TON to tokenTransfer to cover the gas costs in case of sending a transaction with tokens back is also not suitable. Because, in this case, some user can specifically specify such amount of TON that it is enough only to transfer tokens and call tokenNotification transaction, but not more.

And in case I leave some amount of TON on my contract so that it could pay the fee for returning tokens, in case of what happens, there may be an attack when the user will transfer tokens to my contract with invalid data on purpose, so that the checks will fail and my contract will try to send tokens back, thus emptying its TON stock.

@Denys well, you have no other options. If you use default Jetton contracts, you can only make it possible to initiate returning tokens if enough gas was provided. Validadion of data and preventing attacks of some sort is responsibility of R in that case; if S sends tokens with not enough gas for returning, it's their problem – you can only provide a protocol which will return when it is used properly. If they want to loose their Jettons, they can send a smaller TON amount, but what's the point of doing so?

I agree with you, thanks for the reply.

Another question: since in TON contracts can communicate with each other only by sending transactions, it is impossible to get the actual balance of tokens of another contract, because while such a transaction will go through the network, the balance may already change. Are there any options to solve this problem. Still, quite often there is a need to get the balance of tokens, how to be then?

@Denys well, in some cases you can track the balance using a variable in another contract (for instance, if is the owner of the jetton wallet and you can be sure that it will receive all transfer notifications), but this is a fragile approach for specific cases.
(don't forget to upvote/accept the answer, if it is helpful/answers your question)
